# NHibernate Interceptor clarification (on deletion/ dirty)

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I might be in the process of trying something (bad), just to see what I come up with.
For starters, we built an application in a DDD fashion - our opinion. The design is "classic" DDD, meaning we have repositories for aggregate roots.
We do have a base Entity where we override Equals, GetHashCode, etc. Our entities are only logical deleted ie we use an IsActive field.
As ORM we use NHibernate >3.

The thing I'd like to try: I'd like to be able to remove an entity from a list inside an aggregate root with a syntax like this:

```
aggregateRoot.Entities.Remove(entity);
```

In the persistence layer, the default NHibernate behaviour for "entity" ("entity" has a back-reference to "aggregateRoot") is to  update the "entity" with a NULL on "aggregateRoot" column. What we actually want to do is this:

```
repository.Delete(entity);
```

which just marks "entity" as being inactive while "entity" remains in the "aggregateRoot" 's collection.

Most probably my idea is just plain stupid (as I said once again), but I'd like to try to teach NHibernate that "entity" should not be updated with a null reference to "aggregateRoot", just make it inactive. Why? Because I want to use the repository explicitly where it is required.

What I am asking is if this is achievable through NHibernate Interceptors; I haven't tried them yet and I want to prioritize my backlog.

Comment: *"just make it inactive. Why? Because I want to use the repository explicitly where it is required."*

=> I don't get it. Use the repository explicitly to do what ? What do you really want to do with that entity ? Disable it or delete it ?

Comment: I want to disable that entity. I want the domain to be unaware of disabled entities. The business is unaware that when I delete entities, I just disable them.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just implement a Delete method on your entities? You may hide it behind a core interface. The advantage is a completely persistence ignorant implementation which doesn't require NH to exist.

```
class Root
{
  // ...
  public void Remove(Entity entity)
  {
    IRootManaged managed = (IRootManaged)entity
    managed.Delete();
  }
}

class Entity : IRootManaged
{
  // ...
  public bool IsDeleted { get; private set; }

  public void IRootManaged.Delete()
  {
    this.IsDeleted = true;
  }
}
```

Sorry if I missed the point here ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here are my comments: 1. Why should an entity know how to delete itself? After all, entity creation and persistence (including deletion) are not core parts of the business model, so they should be left out of domain model; entity creation should be managed by a factory(one of its flavours) or a builder or a prototype, you get it; entity deletion is managed by a repository, which, depending on DDD flavour (Onion or not) is at the same level with Business Layer, Factories, (at least some)Specifications.

Comment: Because "being inactive while 'entity' remains in the 'aggregateRoot's collection" is not deleted. It is just "marked inactive". The entity doesn't know how it is deleted. But it can definitely know how it is set to "inactive". Deleting is more physical and shouldn't be implemented in the entity.

Comment: 2. I asked if it is possible to intercept, in the persistence layer of choice (here NH), the call that says "hey he pulled out that entity from the collection, let me delete the reference" and override it so that he will act like "hey he pulled out that entity from the collection, so let's marked it as deleted."

Comment: I can't actually follow here. I didn't understand this part: "the default NHibernate behaviour is to update the 'entity' with a NULL on 'aggregateRoot' column". NH does never update anything in the entity. What means "pulled from the collection"? What means "delete the reference"? You may add some mapping and some code to your question.

Comment: I have an entity with a backreference to an aggregate root. I do perform aggregateRoot.Entities.Remove(entity). Here, NH will update the entity with a null reference to the aggregateRoot (the back-reference); of course I don't want NH to actually delete (physically) the item from the DB. What I want is that when I remove an entity from the collection and then go and persist changes, the entity should be marked as inactive but still be member of the collection. This way, I believe, developers will be less stressed with persistence in BLL and the code will speak for itself.

Comment: So I guess that you mapped it as an inverse one-to-many. Why are you removing it from the collection if you want to keep it in the collection? The code doesn't speak for itself if it does something completely different as it looks to do. If you want to keep it in the collection and mark it as deleted, the code should look like this. IMO, everything else is information hiding. You'll see, it is vital to know if the entity gets actually deleted or not.

Comment: It is correct, inverse one-to-many. I am intrigued more by the actual implementation than by its usability, that is a big mistake. The implementation should provide no surprises for the actual user, another mistake I would make.

Answer (score 0):

In a classic DDD, `aggregateRoot.Entities.Remove(entity);` is a bad practice anyway. You'd better create a method on the root entity, say `RemoveEntity(Entity e)`, and there you will encapsulate the *Delete* mechanism in which you will set the Entity.IsActive to false.

Comment: Well I do have a method RemoveEntity(Entity entity); in its implementation I do the above thing, aggregateRoot.Entities.Remove(entity). That is the code from the aggregateRoot domain object, not from business layer.

Comment: Why I don't do IsActive = false in entities? Because I believe that's not its place. It is persistence related, in my opinion. Inactive entities would be brought to life out of band, not part of a business scenario. So, if it's not a business behaviour, it shouldn't be represented in code.

Comment: Suppose you've mangaged to do what you want, and you made Entitiy E1 to be Inactive in the DB, how would you filter out E1 from AR1.Entities when you will fetch AR1?

Comment: You mean how will I ignore the inactive entities attached to an aggregate root. I think of two possibilities: 1) you load them by hand from repository; 2) you run a specification over the tree.

Comment: But you said so yourself - in your opinion, it is persistence related (which i tend to disagree with you), and therefore option 2 is not acceptable. I think it is not persistnece related and option 2 is acceptable, and if so, you don't have to remove the entity from the collection in the first place, since you would use a specification.

Comment: As a general point, with a clear head, I will not implement the feature in the post (I will close the question) since it's not really that okay(thanks Stefan Steinegger for showing the direction). Regarding the repository part, I use a specification every time I want something from DAL, and it's DAL's job interpreting that specification. That means it's okay to create a specification in BLL and pass it to DAL to evaluate and return some data (that's querying). Yes, loading entities is not persistence ignorant, but working with them in business logic, it should be. It lessens the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://ayende.com/blog/4157/avoid-soft-deletes

Comment: Yes, I know what Ayende wrote. I read his blogs and I find them sometimes to be true for a particular context. I beieve it's not our context. We don't delete not because we want to audit (that might not be in plan); imagine that currently we don't have a recycle bin in our application; that doesn't mean there won't be any of it in the (near) future. If you're concerned about query time, we could index on the business key of the entity and the column IsActive and be done with it.